# Sqoop the data from oracle using HDP 2.4 on windows environment

Tags: oracle, sqoop

Sqoop the data from oracle using HDP 2.4 on windows environment

Error message:

> The system can not find the file specified.

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:hud_reader/hud_reader_n1le@huiprd_nile:1527 --username hud_reader --password hud_reader_n1le --table <DATAAGGRUN> --target-dir C:\hadoop\hdp\temp  --m 1`

Help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you add ojdbc6 or ojdbc7 jar in `sqoop/lib`? Please share full error logs.

Comment: yes. I did, but no luck

Comment: **The system can not find the file specified.** is not sufficient error to understand the issue. share full logs.